# PostgreSQL: create stored procedure using dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, dynamic-sql

I am new to PostgreSQL and want to create a stored procedure that will execute data quality queries and place the results into a table.

However, I am running into an error when trying to execute the query

> More than one row returned from subquery

I want all the values that are returned from the query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema_name.sp_perform_data_profiling_test()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

--set for number of possible records;

rec_count int := 5000;

-- dynamic query

query text;

-- used to iterate through catalog table.

rec record;

BEGIN

query :=  'select '
|| 'count(distinct '|| c.column_name ||'::text) as num_distinct '
|| 'sum(case when '|| c.column_name ||'::text is null then 1 else 0 end) num_nulls ' 
|| 'from ' || t.table_schema || '.' || c.table_name 
|| ' ' || CHR(13) || chr(10) ||' ; ' || chr(13) || chr(10)
from information_schema.columns c
inner join information_schema.tables t
on c.table_name = t.table_name
and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.table_schema in ('schema_name')
and c.table_name like 'table_name_%';

for rec in execute query using rec_count

loop

    insert into schema_name.data_profile_col_sum
    (   
        num_distinct, num_nulls


     )
     values
     (
        rec.num_distinct,rec.num_nulls
     );
    
raise notice '%',rec;

end loop;
end;
$BODY$;
```

`call schema_name.sp_perform_data_profiling_test();`

```
ERROR:  query "SELECT 'select '
|| 'count(distinct '|| c.column_name ||'::text) as num_distinct '
|| 'from ' || t.table_schema || '.' || c.table_name 
|| ' ' || CHR(13) || chr(10) ||' ; ' || chr(13) || chr(10)
from information_schema.columns c
inner join information_schema.tables t
on c.table_name = t.table_name
and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.table_schema in ('schema_name')
and c.table_name like 'Table_%_name'" returned more than one row
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function schema_name.sp_perform_data_profiling_test() line 18 at assignment
SQL state: 21000
```

I am expecting a result something like this for each table:

| Num_Distinct | Num_Nulls |
| --- | --- |
| 64 | 0 |
| 8 | 3 |

Comment: The problem is not the execution of the `query`, it is the *building* of the `query` text. You can try to log the `query`, you won't see it.

Comment: The `query := …` appears to be missing a `SELECT`. I'm kinda surprised it doesn't throw a syntax error

Comment: In [43.4. Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-expressions.html), the documentation states that PL/pgSQL evaluates expressions by passing them to the SQL engine as `SELECT` statements. This is why there isn't a syntax error.

Comment: Use the function format() to create the SQL statement. That makes it easier to read but also safer against SQL injection and avoids issues with non-default names

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the stored procedure. In the assignment to `query`, multiple rows are returned. These cannot be assigned to a scalar text variable. The constructed query also has syntax problems; e.g., there is a comma missing after `num_distinct`.

I think I understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps the following query to get the distinct counts and number of NULLs for each column meeting the selection criteria will be of value:

```
SELECT
  c.table_schema,
  c.table_name,
  c.column_name,
  (XPATH('row/num_distinct/text()', t.counts))[1]::text::bigint AS num_distinct,
  (XPATH('row/num_nulls/text()', t.counts))[1]::text::bigint AS num_nulls
FROM
  information_schema.columns c
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT (XPATH('/table/row',
                  QUERY_TO_XML(FORMAT($$SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT %I) AS num_distinct, COALESCE(SUM(1) FILTER (WHERE %I IS NULL), 0) AS num_nulls FROM %I.%I$$,
                                      c.column_name,
                                      c.column_name,
                                      c.table_schema,
                                      c.table_name),
                               FALSE,
                               FALSE,
                               '')))[1] AS counts) t
WHERE c.table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY c.table_schema, c.table_name, c.column_name;
```